# Does ruby sequel support the JSON datatype which Mysql 5.7 introduced?

Tags: ruby, sequel

It does not appear the ruby based [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) toolkit (currently at v4.32.0 I believe) supports the JSON datatype which mysql introduced with v5.7. Can somebody confirm that is true and suggests workarounds for migrations and queries? Also whether there are plans to introduce it.

Comment: Guess this is better to ask on IRC, mailing list or as an issue on the github repo...

Comment: [A search of the code](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=json) reveals that only PostgreSQL related files use `json`, and not MySQL related files. So no, this doesn't seem supported, unless the name `json` is entirely avoided in the MySQL implementation. As for work-arounds, I guess you can just encode and decode the JSON manually ...?

Answer (score 1):

Sequel doesn't currently support MySQL's JSON type.

There aren't any near-future plans to implement support for it, though something like a `mysql_json` extension should be fairly easy to support on the MySQL adapter.  The mysql2 adapter would be trickier as it does all of its own typecasting.